Full Screen Intent is not working when Extend Unlock/Smart Lock is enabled in device
I'm implementing a VOIP call based app, Full screen notification is working fine as expected in other cases. But when extend unlock or smart lock setting is enabled in device, in that case sometimes full screen notification is not coming only a push for call is showing in notification tray.
When I disable the extend unlock, then it is working fine.
I have tried few solutions for this but nothing is working out.
In my code, all the required settings or permissions are given in manifest file.
Manifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />

<activity
    android:name=".ui.puurcall.ringingcall.NewCallActivity"
    android:configChanges="fontScale|uiMode"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PUUR"
    android:turnScreenOn="true" />

In onCreate of NewCallActivity:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

  setContentView(view)
  turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff()
}

fun Activity.turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    setShowWhenLocked(true)
    setTurnScreenOn(true)
  } else {
    window.addFlags(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
    )
  }

  with(getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      requestDismissKeyguard(this@turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff, null)
    }
  }
}


Are you testing this on android 14 ?

Yes, I have tested this on android 14 and 13 both. @BobSmith

When Smart Lock is enabled, use setShowWhenLocked(true), setTurnScreenOn(true), and requestDismissKeyguard() to ensure your full-screen intent works.

@BobSmith I am already doing this in Activity's onCreate(). I have added the code for this in the question.

remove with(getSystemService( block and use val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {         keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)     } else {         window.addFlags(             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED         )     }

Okay, I will check and let you know in sometime @BobSmith

It is not working @BobSmith. With this, FSI notifications stopped working in normal case as well

@Bob Did you find any solution for this ?
